# How to replace new line characters with actual new lines in a string in android?

Tags: android

I need to display a string which contains a lot of new line '\n'.These needs to be replaced with actual newlines in that string. How can I do that in android?

Comment: I'm a bit confused at why you're replacing it with empty strings. You're just deleting the `\n` characters? If you want new lines, you shouldn't delete the `\n`.

Comment: where you want to display new line? In TextView? or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi I have a string str="This is testing\nHow are you?" and when I set it to textview it is displaying the string as it is but "how are you" is not moving to next line.....i.e in textview it is showing "This is testing\nHow are you?"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this..

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stringWriter, true);
writer.println("line1");
writer.println("line2");
writer.println("line3");
useString(stringWriter.toString());
```

`line1, line2 and line3` will be printed in separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = "lots of \n new \n lines";
String newStringWithoutNewLines = myString.replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should concatenate the newline operator like:

```
String str = "This is testing" + "\n" + "How are you?";
```

you said from database you could split like:

```
String[] separated = str.split("\n");
separated[0]; // this will contain "This is testing"
separated[1]; // this will contain "How are you?"
```

and then concatenate them

Comment: Hi the string data is coming from database...so I can't concatenate like that

Comment: the string is from the database like this? "This is testing\nHow are you?"

Comment: yes this a sample string I am showing...but the original text contains lot pf \n characters in it

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is the string you receive from your database contains not the new line character, but rather the characters `\` and `n`. The simplest fix is use simply the `String.replace` function to replace the character sequence `\` `n` by the character `\n` like so:

```
String str = getStringWithFakeNewlines();
str.replace("\\n", "\n"); // The first backslash is doubled to find actual backslashes
```